# Flask: App structure to avoid circular imports

Tags: python, flask

I am following the book *Mastering flask*'s recommended file structure.

(The name of my project is Paw)

In `Paw/paw/__init__.py`:

```
def create_app(object_name):
  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.config.from_object(object_name)

  db.init_app(app)
  robot = LoggingWeRobot(token='banana', enable_session=True)
  robot.init_app(app, endpoint='werobot', rule='/wechat')

  attach_debugging_logger(app)

  app.register_blueprint(poll_blueprint)
  app.register_blueprint(wechat_blueprint)

  return app
```

Note that the robot variable is actually needed in my blueprint, wechat, found in: Paw/paw/controllers/wechat.py

```
@robot.handler
def request_logging_middleware(message, session):
  app.logger.debug("\n%s", request.data)
  return False    # This allows other handlers to continue execution
```

So my problem is that my blueprint has no access to the `robot` variable. However, the `robot` variable should be created in create_app in `Paw/paw/__init__.py` because I am trying to follow the application factory pattern.

Any recommendation on how to fix this? My project can be found [here](https://github.com/vicngtor/Paw/tree/refactoring) and I am trying to follow [this application structure](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-Flask/tree/master/Chapter%205_Code/chapter_5)

Comment: Where is `db` defined? Why not define `robot` there as well?

Comment: because robot needs to `init_app` with the `app` variable

Comment: You do the exact same thing with `db`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the same pattern you are using for `db` - create `robot` elsewhere and import it into your `Paw/paw/__init__.py` file, just as you do with `db`:

```
import db from models
import robot from wechat_setup
# wechat_setup is where you would invoke
# robot = LoggingWeRobot(token='banana', enable_session=True)

def create_app(object_name):
  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.config.from_object(object_name)

  db.init_app(app)
  robot.init_app(app, endpoint='werobot', rule='/wechat')
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually put project global variables in one file (say `gvars.py`).

Then the project structure will be some sort like this:

```
.
├── etc
│   └── webapp.py
├── models
│   └── common.py
├── views
│   └── common.py
├── gvars.py
└── webapp.py
```

In other files we just do this:

```python
from gvars import db, robot # or other variables
```